# Class java.io.FileInputStream for Android Q

Tags: file-io, android-10.0

A library I am using JID3 which uses the Class java.io.FileInputStream written by A. von Hoff
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_van_Hoff

Stacktrace:

```
2020-08-08 14:09:23.164 23212-23212/com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
2020-08-08 14:09:23.164 23212-23212/com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/AD7D-190E/Music/Gerry Rafferty/City to City/01 - The Ark.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2020-08-08 14:09:23.164 23212-23212/com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
2020-08-08 14:09:23.164 23212-23212/com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
2020-08-08 14:09:23.164 23212-23212/com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager W/System.err:     at org.blinkenlights.jid3.io.FileSource.getInputStream(FileSource.java:86)
2020-08-08 14:09:23.164 23212-23212/com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager W/System.err:     at org.blinkenlights.jid3.MP3File.getID3V2Tag(MP3File.java:455)
```

Has anyone amended this to allow file operations under Android Q (api29) and above ?

Comment: `FileInputStream` does not need to be amended. Are you referring to JID3 needing to be amended?

Comment: Yes, jid3 will need amending to be able to open files under SAF.